# Unicode conversion, database woes (Delphi 2007 to XE2)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, delphi, unicode, ansi

Currently, I am in the process of updating all of our Delphi 2007 code base to Delphi XE2. The biggest consideration is the ANSI to Unicode conversion, which we've dealt with by re-defining all base types (char/string) to ANSI types (ansichar/ansistring). This has worked in many of our programs, until I started working with the database.

The problem started when I converted a program that stores information read from a file into an SQL Server 2008 database. Suddenly simple queries that used a string to locate data would fail, such as:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'something'
```

The `name` field is a `varchar`. I found that I was able to complete the query successfully by prefixing the string name with an `N`.  I was under the impression that `varchar` could *only* store ANSI characters, but it appears to be storing Unicode?

Some more information: the name field in Delphi is `string[13]`, but I've tried dropping the `[13]`.  The database collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.  We use ADO to interface with the database.  The connection information is stored in the ODBC Administrator.

NOTE: I've solved my actual problem thanks to a bit of direction from Panagiotis.  The name we read from our map file is an `array[1..24] of AnsiChar`.  This value was being implicitly converted to `string[13]`, which was including null characters.  So a name with 5 characters was really being stored as the 5 characters + 8 null characters in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*varchar* fields do NOT store Unicode characters. They store ASCII values in the codepage specified by the field's collation. SQL Server will [try to convert characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175074%28v=sql.105%29) to the correct codepage when you try to store Unicode or data from a different codepage. You can disable this feature but the best option is to avoid the whole mess by using *nvarchar* fields and UnicodeString in your application.

You mention that you changes all character types to ANSI, not UNICODE types in your application. If you want to use UNICODE you should be using a UNICODE type like UnicodeString. Otherwise your values will be converted to ANSI when they are sent to your server. This conversion is done by your code when you create the AnsiString that is sent to the server.

BTW, your select statement stores an ASCII value in the field. You have to prepend the value with N if you want to store it as a unicode value, eg.g

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = N'something'
```

Even this will not guarantee that your data will reach the server in a Unicode form. If you store the statement in an AnsiString the entire statement is converted to ANSI before it is sent to the server. If your app makes a wrong conversion, you will end up with mangled data on the server.

The solution is very simple, just use parameterized statements to pass unicode values as unicode parameters and store them in NVarchar fields. It is much faster, avoids all conversion errors and prevents SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am very limited by what I can change.  I would love to completely embrace Unicode, but half of the system is written with Visual C++ 4.2.  We also share some code with a vastly more complicated system where a true Unicode conversion isn't fiscally possible.  I will take what you've said and try to better diagnose where the the issue is occurring.